# Page number position - exact height

Tags: fancyhdr, geometry

How can I adjust the page layout as described in the figure below?
I tried it with the code below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\geometry{ a4paper, total={210mm,297mm}, left=27.5mm, right=27.5mm, top=30mm, bottom=20mm}
\voffset =-3mm
\headsep=1cm
\headheight=10pt
\marginparwidth=0pt
\marginparsep=0pt
\oddsidemargin=0pt
\evensidemargin=0pt
\hoffset=2.1mm
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\begin{document}

How can I adjust the page layout as described in the figure below?

I tried the above minimal working code...

Thanks in advance...

Note: I don't want the underline ..

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\end{document}
```

[image: page layout]

Comment: For small adjustments, you can put `\thepage` inside a `\raisebox` within the fancyhead code.

Answer (score 2):

```
\usepackage[%showframe,%
  a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=2.75cm,right=2.75cm,%
  headheight=14.5pt,headsep=1cm]{geometry}
```

Use the option `showframe` to see what's going on.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage[%showframe,%
  a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=2.75cm,right=2.75cm,%
  headheight=14.5pt,headsep=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\begin{document}

How can I adjust the page layout as described in the figure below ?

I tried the above minimal working code...

Thanks in advance...

Note : I don't want the underline ..

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are loading geometry, showframe is an option.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Right, thanks, I've modifed the answer.